# Efficient C/C++ algorithm on 2-dimensional max-sum window

Tags: c++, algorithm, sliding-window

I have a `c[N][M]` matrix where I apply a max-sum operation over a `(K+1)²` window. I am trying to reduce the complexity of the naive algorithm.

In particular, here's my code snippet in C++:

```
<!-- language: cpp -->

int N,M,K;
std::cin >> N >> M >> K;

std::pair< unsigned , unsigned > opt[N][M];
unsigned c[N][M];

// Read values for c[i][j]
// Initialize all opt[i][j] at (0,0).

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i ++ ) {
  for ( int j = 0; j < M ; j ++ ) {

    unsigned max = 0;
    int posX = i, posY = j;

    for ( int ii = i; (ii >= i - K) && (ii >= 0); ii -- ) {
      for ( int jj  = j; (jj >= j - K) && (jj >= 0); jj -- ) {

        // Ignore the (i,j) position
        if (( ii == i ) && ( jj == j )) {
          continue;
        }

        if ( opt[ii][jj].second > max ) {

          max = opt[ii][jj].second;
          posX = ii;
          posY = jj;

        }
      }
    }

    opt[i][j].first  = opt[posX][posY].second;
    opt[i][j].second = c[i][j] + opt[posX][posY].first;

  }
}
```

The goal of the algorithm is to compute `opt[N-1][M-1]`.

Example: for `N = 4, M = 4, K = 2` and:

```
c[N][M] = 4 1 1 2
          6 1 1 1
          1 2 5 8
          1 1 8 0
```

... the result should be `opt[N-1][M-1] = {14, 11}`.

The running complexity of this snippet is however **O**(N M K²). My goal is to **reduce** the running time complexity. I have already seen posts like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732841/sliding-window-minimum-maximum-in-2d)**, but it appears that my "filter" is not separable, probably because of the sum operation.

---

More information (**optional**): this is essentially an algorithm which develops the optimal strategy in a "game" where:

- Two players lead a single team in a `N × M` dungeon.
- Each position of the dungeon has `c[i][j]` gold coins.
- Starting position: `(N-1,M-1)` where `c[N-1][M-1] = 0`.
- The active player chooses the next position to move the team to, from position `(x,y)`.
- The next position can be any of `(x-i, y-j), i <= K, j <= K, i+j > 0`. In other words, they can move only left and/or up, up to a step `K` per direction.
- The player who just moved the team gets the coins in the new position.
- The active player alternates each turn.
- The game ends when the team reaches `(0,0)`.
- Optimal strategy for both players: maximize their own sum of gold coins, if they know that the opponent is following the same strategy.

Thus, `opt[i][j].first` represents the coins of the player who will now move from `(i,j)` to another position. `opt[i][j].second` represents the coins of the opponent.

Comment: `if (( ii = i ) && ( jj = j ))` should be `if (( ii == i ) && ( jj == j ))`

Comment: In your optional game description, how much do the players know about the distribution of coins? Nothing, all inside their K-window, or the complete distribution? Anyways, that looks loke a good application for dynamic programming. I'll write an answer this evening if it hasn't already been done.

Comment: @Baiz, thank you for the correction. It's indeed `==`, I've just fixed it.
@davidhigh, the players know the coins distribution on the whole map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `O(N * M)` solution.

1. Let's fix the lower row(`r`). If the maximum for all rows between `r - K` and `r` is known for every column, this problem can be reduced to a well-known sliding window maximum problem. So it is possible to compute the answer for a fixed row in `O(M)` time.
2. Let's iterate over all rows in increasing order. For each column the maximum for all rows between `r - K` and `r` is the sliding window maximum problem, too. Processing each column takes `O(N)` time for all rows.

The total time complexity is `O(N * M)`. 
However, there is one issue with this solution: it does not exclude the `(i, j)` element. It is possible to fix it by running the algorithm described above twice(with `K * (K + 1)` and `(K + 1) * K` windows) and then merging the results(a `(K + 1) * (K + 1)` square without a corner is a union of two rectangles with `K * (K + 1)` and `(K + 1) * K` size).

Comment: The question wasn't very explicit about this, but it's not a traditional sliding window problem, because the values are not all available offline.

Comment: I have read the question again, but I still can't find where it says that the values are not available offline.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat all values `c[i][j]` are available. I've also commented on the original post.

Comment: @Adama Of `c` but not `opt`, which is what you're sliding the window over.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, that's correct then. You don't have the previous values available; to compute `opt[x][y]` you have to know all `opt[x-i][y-j]`, `0 <= i,j <= K` beforehand. Thus, you need to do the computations left -> right and top -> bottom.

Comment: @user2040251 Assume I apply two windows: `K x L` and `L x K`, with `L = K+1`. Then `opt[x][y] = max( winLK(x-1,y), winKL(x,y-1) )`, where `winLK(x,y) = max(x-i,y-j), 0 <= i <= K+1, 0 <= j <= K`. However, now I want to calculate `opt[x][y+1]`; how can I take into account the new value of `opt[x][y]` without rerunning the window algorithm? My gut feeling is that I need to run two windows and a final `N x M` pass, but I'm still a bit confused on the merging part.

Comment: I just figured it out: there should indeed be two independent windows, K x (K+1) and (K+1) x K. However, we slowly slide and update these windows as we update opt[x][y], operations that should take O(1). So, the final complexity is indeed O(N*M). Thank you.