# Maximums of all 2D subarrays of size A x B

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

Let's say I have a 2D array of size `N x M`. I want to print out the *sum* of the *maximum* of every subarray of size `A x B`.

For example, let's say for this `3 x 3` array, `A = 2` and `B = 2`.

```
Input:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

the output should be:

```
Output:
from (0, 0) to (1, 1): 5
from (0, 1) to (1, 2): 6
from (1, 0) to (2, 1): 8
from (1, 1) to (2, 2): 9

Answer: 5 + 6 + 8 + 9 = 28
```

I've tried using a 2D Sparse Table, but it's definitely not fast enough. I'm trying to achieve `O(N * M)`, if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791775/6022817) describes  a way of extending the 1-D (array) algorithm for finding the [maximum over a sliding window](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k/) (please read Method 3, the one that uses a deque). Essentially:

1. Find the maximum of every horizontal sequence of *B* elements, effectively reducing the matrix to *N* - *B* + 1 columns.
2. Find the maximum of every vertical sequence of *A* elements, effectively reducing the matrix to *M* - *A* + 1 rows.
3. The remaining elements are your window maxima, simply add them up.